# Не выворобушкивайся - скороговорка?

Tags: словообразование, значение-слов

Не выворобушкивайся - это из скороговорки какой-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел!

> Реструктуризация из-под выподверта сиреневенькой глазовыколупывательницы с полувывернутыми ножками это полный бесперcпективняк, так что сиди и не выворобушкивайся.

Comment: Здорово! Не знала такой.И сразу бы так. Какая разница, кто будет гуглить - Вы или мы? В памяти такого сразу не найдёшь.

Comment: А мне кажется, это полезно, Людмила, если кто-то задаёт интересный вопрос, на который сам может найти ответ, и даже сам может на него ответить, если никто не опередит его с исчерпывающим ответом. Зато другие что-то интересное узнают! Как Вы считаете (и все остальные тоже)? Сайт этого разве не предполагает (или хотя бы не допускает)? По крайней мере, я хочу сказать спасибо за этот вопрос, интересное слово узнал. ;)

Comment: Точнее за смешную поговорку или просто фразу спасибо, повеселили.))